# Kotlin script doesn't find Ktor CIO class

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-script

I'm trying to use [kotlin-main-kts](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md#kotlin-main-kts) with a Ktor client.

Here is my simple Kotlin script in a file named `ktor_tests.main.kts`:

```kotlin
@file:Repository("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2")
@file:DependsOn("io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:1.5.3")
@file:DependsOn("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.5.3")

import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIO

println("Hello")

HttpClient(CIO).use {
    println("In client scope.")
}
```

I run it with

```
kotlinc -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-main-kts/1.4.21/kotlin-main-kts-1.4.21.jar -script ktor_tests.main.kts
```

and the output is

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
error: unresolved reference: CIO (clean_location_group.main.kts:6:34)
error: unresolved reference: CIO (clean_location_group.main.kts:10:12)
clean_location_group.main.kts:6:34: error: unresolved reference: CIO
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIO
                                 ^
clean_location_group.main.kts:10:12: error: unresolved reference: CIO
HttpClient(CIO).use {
           ^
```

My Kotlin/JVM version is: kotlinc-jvm 1.4.31 (JRE 11.0.10+9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `-jvm` suffix to the `io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.5.3` dependency as you did for `ktor-client-core`:

```
@file:DependsOn("io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:1.5.3")
@file:DependsOn("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:1.5.3")
```